# Микроразметка shema.org в MODX Revolution

Tags: javascript, php, html, modx, breadcrumbs

Подскажите пожалуйста такой момент.
Я добавляю микроразметку, но валидатор требует чтобы у каждой крошки был мета-тег position (`<meta itemprop="position" content="тут номер элемента" />`).

Проблема в том, что нужно сделать счетчик именно в коде MODX, чтобы в content ставился индекс крошки, у меня даже идей особо нету как это сделать.

Вот весь код хлебных крошек:

```
[[BreadCrumb?
&containerTpl=`@INLINE <ul id="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">[[+crumbs]]</ul>`
&homeCrumbTpl=`@INLINE <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a href="[[+link]]" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">[[+pagetitle]]</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="" /></li>`
&currentCrumbTpl=`@INLINE <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><span itemprop="name">[[+pagetitle]]</span><meta itemprop="position" content="" /></li>`
&linkCrumbTpl=`@INLINE <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a href="[[+link]]" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">[[+pagetitle]]</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="" /></li>`
&categoryCrumbTpl=`@INLINE <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a href="[[+link]]" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">[[+pagetitle]]</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="" /></li>`
&maxCrumbTpl=`@INLINE <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><span itemprop="name">...</span></li>`]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Могу только предложить использовать pdoCrumbs из библиотеки pdoTools (https://modx.com/extras/package/pdotools?version=557c464fdc532f69510518f6) там есть чанк `[[+idx]]` который содержит порядковый номер элемента.

Документация: https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdocrumbs

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

В последней версии Breadcrumb 1.4.4 добавлен плейсхолдер [[+position]], так что можете использовать плагин без костылей сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Cниппет `BreadCrumb` не поддерживает плейсхолдер для значений порядковых номеров элементов.

Посмотрите в сторону использования сниппета `pdoCrumbs`.

Если по каким-то причинам вы хотите решить задачу на сниппете `Breadcrumb`, то вы можете добавить требуемый плейсхолдер сами, слегка изменив его код:

1. Добавить перед строкой [127](https://github.com/benjamin-vauchel/BreadCrumb/blob/77340f2a9ac43b7ea899eae7109b7a82650a82ef/core/components/breadcrumb/elements/snippets/breadcrumb.snippet.php#L127):

```
$bc = 0;
```

2. Изменить строку [164](https://github.com/benjamin-vauchel/BreadCrumb/blob/77340f2a9ac43b7ea899eae7109b7a82650a82ef/core/components/breadcrumb/elements/snippets/breadcrumb.snippet.php#L164) на следующую:

```
$placeholders = array_merge($resource->toArray(), array('link' => $link, 'idx' => ++$bc));
```

После этого вы сможете использовать плейсхолдер `[[+idx]]`

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли!

Comment: @user352638, если мой ответ оказался полезен - примите его, кликом на галочке ;)